# Why does XML have such verbose closing tags?

Tags: xml, verbosity

Yes, this probably shouldn't bug me.

But it does!!

Why does XML have such verbose closing tags? Not only does it make documents uglier for humans, it needlessly introduces the risk of mismatched (or misspelled!) opening and closing tags.

Even if we wanted to require closing tags, *why* do we need to include the name of the opening tag inside the closing tag?  There is never any ambiguity in XML, because innermost tags **must** be closed before closing outer tags!

For example:

```
<thisIsSomewhatLong>
    Hello, world!
</thisIsSomewhatLong>
```

...is so much more verbose than:

```
<thisIsSomewhatLong>
    Hello, world!
</>
```

And it doesn't resolve **any** ambiguity, either for humans or for computers.

Does anyone know what the rationale is for this rule? What risks are avoided by disallowing empty closing tags?

Comment: Why does it matter? It is what it is.

Comment: Because someone out there hates us.

Comment: Everyone answered with similar thoughts: it's difficult to find mistakes in XML documents when you can't determine which element wasn't properly closed, and it would become nearly impossible for humans read non-indented XML documents if closing tags were all empty. I marked Jack's answer as *the* answer because it had the most votes, though I really liked Michael's, too.

Comment: Gaby, I shall never again type "innermost" as "inner most". >.<

Comment: There are bigger problems with XML, such as trying to manipulate a complex graph with text instead of graphics...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because it improves readability, **XML** was born not to be efficient or concise, just to be easy to work with.. and if you think having `</>` wouldn't create ambiguities it is just because you are indenting the code. If you leave out indentation (which is a really weaker constraint compared to having the name in a closing tag) then it becomes a mess.

A simple example?

```
<A><B><C><D>foo</><D>bar</></><H>baz</></></>
```

You think it's so readable? It's hard to understand where `<H>` is without counting closing tags..

Comment: Hmmm. I understand your point (and the others, too). In this example, though, I think indentation would be needed to make it readable *with or without* closing tags.

Comment: Yes, but indentation is not constrained (nor so portable between text editors if you use tabs instead that multiple spaces). Of course it is a good habit but with closing tags you would have `<H>baz</H></B>` and you would at least know how deep it is in the node tree.

Comment: In any case most of good XML editors are able to close tags automatically so no additional worries :)

Comment: There are markup languages that use indentation, eg [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/). Works well for data-oriented storage, less well for arbitrary document-like content (imagine writing HTML where you couldn't let an `<em>` split over a line, for example).

Answer (score 17):

I can see one big advantage: missing closing tags are caught (by the human or computer) right away, rather than getting an error like `Insufficient closing tags provided; please read through your 1000 line file and figure out where it happened.`

Comment: Hahahaha. I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: That's exactly how most C/C++/C# compilers work... they'll get to the end of your 1,000-line file and then say "Syntax error - unexpected EOF at line 999 - expected }"

Comment: Dylan, good point.  Although I'd argue you have bigger problems you end up with a 1000 line file to begin with!

Comment: What's wrong with a 1000 line file?

Comment: @Andy: A file containing 1000 line of code is usually a sign for a problem, 1000 lines of data (which XML is) is just a tiny drop.

Comment: @LieRyan Where did I say a 1000 line data file is a problem?  I was specifically talking about a 1000 program.

Comment: @Andy: ah, now that makes sense; I thought you were referring to the hypothetical error message in Michael Kopinsky's post, I just can't read.

Answer (score 9):

What you suggest amounts to S-Expression. You know, the thingy all Lisp is written in, e.g. `(thisisSomewhatLong Hello, world!)`. There are indeed some who argue that this is better, because it is way less verbose. They are right, it *is* less verbose. But like it or not, this verbosity also has advantages. Most notably, it allows *early* error detection. With SExprs or similar, missing a close paren or having one too much that means "there are mismatched parens, good luck finding you" (if you're lucky - if you make such a mistake twice, it evens out and could easily screw all the markup - although it could of course yield a structure that doesn't conform the schema (assuming you have something like this) which can allow slightly better error reporting).

Also see ["XML is not S-Expressions"](http://www.prescod.net/xml/sexprs.html).

Comment: The arguments over nothing whether one of these formats is better just shows how plaintext formats are braindead.

Answer (score 3):

Although you might read on the net otherwise, XML is primarily computer readable, and therefore, uses opening and closing tags for validity checking.

It is somewhat human readable; it is efficient for storing data that will be used by many applications, but ultimately, these tags exist so a parser can read that data, check if tags match and do something meaningful with it.

Many people don't like XML's verboseness, so if you don't also, don't worry. You're not alone.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is for readability, as mentioned above.  However, it violates the DRY principle and thus introduces a source of errors, and of course it bloats your document size, which doubly sucks if you're passing it around over a network, which is a common thing to do these days.

True, you don't need to count closing tags, but that's offset by the risk of errors like this:

```
<color>red</colour>
```

Redundant definitions that must always be kept in sync = stress.  That's why I pretty much boycott XML (when possible) and choose YAML, which does not suffer from this problem and is otherwise every bit as expressive as XML (minus the DTDs, which in all my years have yet to demonstrate any value to me).

Another alternative is JSON, which similarly avoids this redundancy problem, but JSON lacks internal references, and in any case YAML is a full superset of JSON.

Comment: Xml isn't code; its parsed by code, but its not code.  I don't think DRY applies outside of coding.

Comment: In my opinion DRY is just as applicable to markup as it is to code, as well as to any other instruction set (cooking recipes, music notation, mathematical proofs, etc).  It goes well beyond coding; it's a fundamental principal of effective information management.

Answer (score 1):

The risk is to get lost in

```
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </>
   </>
  </>
 </>
</>
```

BTW, it can validated fine without end-tag names.