# Are XML/HTML tag names inside closing tags really necessary?

Tags: xml, tags, language-design

This is really not a programming question *per se*, but I was wondering why the name of the tag is required in a closing tag in XML. For instance, couldn't

```
<a>
    <b>stuff</b>
</a>
```

Be written

```
<a>
    <b>stuff</>
</>
```

So that each closing tag `</>` merely terminated the last opened tag?

So my questions are

1. Would this work (i.e. are there any corner cases I'm not thinking of in which this would be ambiguous/fail)?
2. If it would work, why didn't 'they' design it that way?

Comment: Smells like SGML. SGML also allows things like `<t/stuff/` but SGML was simplified to get XML so that it would be easier to work with and parse.

Comment: I agree with "mu is too short". To add, It needs to follow the XML concept of "Well-formedness", Section 2.1 of the XML 1.0 recommendation (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) lists this.

Comment: Further to my last comment, SGML was intended to be written by hand so there were a lot shortcuts, XML is meant to be built with software support (either an XML editor or generated wholly by software) so a simpler/faster parser is more important than shortcuts.

Comment: What would be the benefit of having `</>` instead of an actual closing tag?

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close. It is both constructive and a real question, and a good one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does XML have such verbose closing tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370488/why-does-xml-have-such-verbose-closing-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If it would work, why didn't 'they' design it that way?

One reason is that SGML/XML are also designed to be human readable. Your `/a/b` example is readable, but a structure much more complex would be a nightmare to try to interpret.

This would especially be true with mixed content (PCDATA and element structures mixed).

Answer (score 2):

It would work, but it would be awful to debug a nesting issue. For example:

```
<one><two><nine></><ten></><eight><three></><four>
<five></><six></></>
<seven></>To what element does this text belong?</></></>
```

If you make sure the XML has proper indentation, the nesting issue isn't a problem (below is the same code with proper indentation. Yet because indentation is insignificant, we need another mechanism to keep the XML human-readable. In this example, human-readable means a human can easily see which content belongs to which element. The solution is to name which element each closing tag refers to.

```
<one>
<two>
    <nine>
    </nine>
    <ten>
    </ten>
    <eight>
        <three>
        </>
        <four>
            <five>
            </>
            <six>
            </>
        </>
        <seven>
        </>
        To what element does this text belong?
    </>
</>
</>
```

When we give the closing tags names, even it's clear to see even in improperly indented XML that the text belongs to element `<eight>`.

```
<one><two><nine></nine><ten></ten><eight><three></three><four>
<five></five><six></six></four><seven>
</seven>To what element does this text belong?</eight></two></one>
```